# OpenAL alDistanceModel Gain/Attenuation

Tags: c++, openal

Hello I am doing a project with OpenAL. I was trying to get alDistanceModel to work but it doesn't seem to work. I looked at the OpenAL Manuel that goes into depth about it but I am still confused.

I have a map of source_id: std::map source_id;
it holds the actual buffer key and stores the source id.

I also have a map of the buffers std:: buffer_handle.

I grab the buffer_handle map send in a .wav file for a string and the buffer_handle map returns a valid handle. then I do the same thing, I use the returned buffer_handle value to get the source_id.

In the set_attenuation function I am pretty sure that I have set the correct variables. but the sound just plays with a normal Gain of 1, when I am close, far away. So what I did was I manually did the equation and that worked but i doubt that's the right way to do it.

The Distance variable is calculated by using the distance formula from the listener to where the audio will be played.

RefDistance variable, I believe is the radius of how wide the area is so then you can calculate it with the distance to determine the right gain/attenuation.

So to bring it all together, am I doing something wrong? does OpenAL internally do the equation and then updates it appropriately? because OpenAL didn't do anything before I manually perform this equation.

```
 void cacctus_audio_manager::play(const ALuint& source, const ALuint& buffer,bool 
  loop,std::ostringstream& _debug)
  {
      set_attenuation(source);
      if (loop)
          {
              alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);
          }
          else
          {
              alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);
          }
          alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buffer_id);
          alSourcePlay(source);
  }

#define MAX_GAIN 1.0f
#define MIN_GAIN 0.00f
#define REFERENCE_DISTANCE 10.0f
#define MAX_DISTANCE 125.0f
#define MIN_DISTANCE 0.0f
#define ROLL_OFF_FACTOR 1.0f;



set_attenuation(const ALuint& source)
{
    alDistanceModel(AL_EXPONENT_DISTANCE_CLAMPED);
    alSourcef(source, AL_ROLLOFF_FACTOR, 1);
    alSourcef(source, AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE,REFERENCE_DISTANCE);
    alSourcef(source, AL_MAX_DISTANCE,MAX_DISTANCE);
    alSourcef(source, AL_MAX_GAIN, MAX_GAIN);
    alSourcef(source, AL_MIN_GAIN, MIN_GAIN);

    ALfloat mRefDist = REFERENCE_DISTANCE;
    ALfloat mVolume = 0;
    ALfloat mRolloffvalue = ROLL_OFF_FACTOR;
    alGetSourcef(source,AL_GAIN,&mVolume);
    _distance = std::max(_distance,mRefDist);
    mVolume = std::pow((_distance / mRefDist),(-mRolloffvalue));
    alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN,mVolume);
}
```

Comment: Just guessing; Maybe AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE_CLAMPED is what you want?

Comment: I have tried all settings for alDistanceModel. I still only get a gain of 1. No matter what position I am at. that's why I ended up making my own equation, which ended up being the actual exponent equation that OpenAL uses.

Comment: maybe I am being dumb and I am doing something wrong. maybe I am just not understanding on how OpenAL uses there Attenuation properly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your buffers contain sound in MONO format? Because if not: according to the OpenAL documentation https://openal.org/documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf if source attached to a buffer with STEREO sound, this source is no longer affected by distance calculations. Quote from doc on page 21:

> 8-bit PCM data is expressed as an unsigned value over the range 0 to
> 255, 128 being an audio output level of zero. 16-bit PCM data is
> expressed as a signed value over the range -32768 to 32767, 0 being an
> audio output level of zero. Stereo data is expressed in interleaved
> format, left channel first. **Buffers containing more than one channel
> of data will be played without 3D spatialization.**

So first make sure your buffer is configured with AL_FORMAT_MONO8 or AL_FORMAT_MONO16 formats before making further research of a problem.